# Convert datetime to seconds for multiple dates in time series data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have date in this format '26:10:2022 09:49:46:000' which continues for multiple days in a time series dataset. I want to convert it to seconds for each time step, i.e., the output should be amount of seconds for the particular day in that year. For e.g. the number of seconds at 4:1:2022 00:00:00:000 should be 259,200 seconds from first day of its year 1:1:2022 00:00:00:000 and so on. Could someone please help in this matter?

I am unable to do it using below way as it resets to zero after each day.

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'].str.strip(), format="%d:%m:%Y %H:%M:%S:%f")
df['Seconds_data'] = df['DateTime'].dt.second
```

Answer (score 0):

How about manually calculating the seconds past? Transform the past days, past months and past minutes into seconds and then adding them together

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood your question correctly, you can get the year from `DateTime` column, construct the date `1-1-<year>`, convert it to datetime and substract it from from the `DateTime` column.

Then use `.dt.total_seconds()` function:

```py
df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(
    df["DateTime"].str.strip(), format="%d:%m:%Y %H:%M:%S:%f"
)

df["Seconds_data"] = (
    (
        df["DateTime"]
        - pd.to_datetime("1-1-" + df["DateTime"].dt.year.astype(str))
    )
    .dt.total_seconds()
    .astype(int)
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
             DateTime  Seconds_data
0 2022-10-26 09:49:46      25782586
1 2022-01-04 00:00:00        259200
```